# I have created a association in rails on a author(has_many) and book(belongs_to), Now upon deleting the author(dependent: :destroy), i get exeception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

2.7.2 :004 > Author.find(1).delete
Author Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "authors".* FROM "authors" WHERE "authors"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Author Destroy (1.0ms)  DELETE FROM "authors" WHERE "authors"."id" = ?  [["id", 1]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey (SQLite3::ConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed: DELETE FROM "authors" WHERE "authors"."id" = ?)

This is the exception i get when i perform delete.

My Author Model Looks like, also used nullify

```
class Author < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :books, dependent: :destroy
end
```

My Book model looks like this

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :author
end
```

I can destroy the author and the record gets deleted and also destroy the books against that author id, now i want to just delete the author and want the books to remain there or get nullify, but it throws an exception when i delete it

Schema

```
create_table 'authors', force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string 'name'
    t.integer 'age'
    t.datetime 'created_at', null: false
    t.datetime 'updated_at', null: false
  end

  create_table 'books', force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string 'name'
    t.integer 'price'
    t.integer 'author_id'
    t.datetime 'created_at', null: false
    t.datetime 'updated_at', null: false
    t.index ['author_id'], name: 'index_books_on_author_id'
```

ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey (SQLite3::ConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed: DELETE FROM "authors" WHERE "authors"."id" = ?)

Comment: Can you post Book model, it is very helpful to help you :)

Comment: the constraint is related to your migration; it's created an index in the database. you should also post your generated schema. Also, look into formatting your code and pastes :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to nullify author_id you need to create a migration to remove the foreign key and run it:

```
class RemoveAuthorForeignKeyFromBooks < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    remove_foreign_key :books, :authors
  end
end
```

`remove_foreign_key` [did not work properly on SQLite before Rails 6](https://www.bigbinary.com/blog/rails-6-adds-add_foreign_key-and-remove_foreign_key-for-sqlite3) so you may need a workaround on older versions.

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :author, optional: true
end

class Author < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :books, dependent: :nullify
end
```

If you don't make the belongs_to relation option then you will not be able to update the book after nullifying the author_id.